# How can I track a value of a boolean at runtime?

Tags: c, struct, boolean

I want to define a boolean which tracks the values of two other booleans and updates dynamically when they change, how can I achieve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct candle_s {
    bool is_on;
    int flame_size;
}candle_t;

typedef struct led_s {
    bool is_on;
    int ampers;
}led_t;

typedef struct light_s {
    bool is_any_on;
    candle_t candle;
    led_t led;
}light_t;

int main()
{
    light_t light1;

    light1.led = {0, 10};
    light1.candle = {1, 20};
    light1.is_any_on = light1.led.is_on | light1.candle.is_on;

    printf("Is any on: %d, is light on %d, is candle on %d\n",
            light1.is_any_on, light1.led.is_on, light1.candle.is_on);

    light1.candle.is_on = 0;

    printf("Is any on: %d, is light on %d, is candle on %d\n",
            light1.is_any_on, light1.led.is_on, light1.candle.is_on);

    return 0;
}
```

### Program output:

```
Is any on: 1, is light on 0, is candle on 1
Is any on: 1, is light on 0, is candle on 0
```

How can I make is_any_on "0"?

I could achieve this with a function, but can I do it otherwise?
I guess using boolean pointer won't help much either, since I am interested in the result of two boolean values.

Comment: There's no such magic in C. You need to write a function that looks at the inputs.

Comment: Right, just define a function. Since it's short the compiler will probably inline it, so there should be little overhead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a function:

```
bool is_any_on(light_t *light)
{
    return light->led.is_on || light->candle.is_on;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
is_any_on(&light1)
```